# Replace content css via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to replace the content from a tag in CSS via jQuery.

In this case the content "My content" to "New Content".

I have this CSS code :

```
a.appari:focus:after{
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  content: "My content";
  left: 20%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 400px;
}
```

I tried this jQuery code :

```
function prova() {
{
 ?>
<script>
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.appari').click(function(){         
      $("<style>.appari:focus:after { content: 'New Content'; }</style>").appendTo( "head" )
  });
});

})(jQuery);
</script>

<?php

  }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a CSS specificity issue. Change the selector in your jQuery to have enough or more specificity than the original rule. You can just add an `a` to `.appari` so it's `a.appari` (matches your original CSS specificity)

```
$("<style>a.appari:focus:after { content: 'New Content'; }</style>").appendTo("head")
```

```js
$('.appari').click(function() {
  $("<style>a.appari:focus:after { content: 'New Content'; }</style>").appendTo("head");
});
```

```css
a.appari:focus:after {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: "My content";
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="appari">foo</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now Works!